# Want to access database data between pages in node.js / ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

My goal is to display logged in / sessioned  username and quiz points in each page after user is logged in and increase user score once quiz answers are correct .

What I am thinking  is I can make a simple javascript based quiz and then at end update the score in mongodb database . But I am confused about the flow and am finding difficulty in calculating score (like + , - ) in ejs pages .

**So , my question is :**

1. Please can anyone guide me through easy , neat and clean flow / code for the same .
2. This is my home.ejs where I need to display logged in  user name and score( at first 0 as entered in mongodb)

```
<%- include("./partials/header") %>
<script>
console.log("hello");
console.log(user.score);
</script>


<div class="container mt-5">
    <a href="/logout" class="btn btn-danger">Logout</a>
    <h2>Welcome <%= user.username %> </h2>
     <div style="align-items: right;">

    Total Points :<%= user.score %>

    </div>

    </div>

<%- include("./partials/footer") %>
```

// here I am getting NAN , console.log(score) also didnt display.

3. This is my  index.js where I rendered  logged in user data to home.ejs page.

```
app
   .get("/home", authenticateUser, (req, res) => {
    res.render("home", { user: req.session.user });
  });

app
  .post("/login", async (req, res) => {
    const { username, password } = req.body;

   req.session.user = {
      username,
    };
   res.redirect('/home');
```

4. This is my User model.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/user");
const UserSchemas = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },

  score: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
 
});

module.exports = new mongoose.model("Users", UserSchemas);
```

5. This is my data in mongodb database.

```
{"_id :{"$oid":"5ff33d071dc86a122cd52969"},
"username":"abc",
"password":"$2b$12$/EG.kUTw69Llt0bNkorJkeOrPWq3AkrJzmNlrzr3qlBPDDhwxqib6",
"score":0,
"__v":0}
```

**Summary : My goal is to update logged in users score upon quiz score . Thats it , nothing much. Currently , I am able to get logged in username on all the pages , but not score ,console.log(score) also didnt worked ,also I need to add/ subtract as per quiz performance.**

A simple , easy , need code/hack or help would be good.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

you are getting null when you try to log score in becuase in ejs you are trying to access the score property of user

```
Total Points :<%= user.score %>
```

but you are never setting the score of the user in your app.js when he/she logs in

```
app.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;
  req.session.user = {
    username,
  };
  res.redirect('/home');
}
```

So when you set the username property of req.session.user you should also set the score property along with it

Like so

```
app.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;
  req.session.user = {
    username:username,
    score:0,
  };
  res.redirect('/home');
}
```

Comment: @codebot thanks , yes I did the similar thing ... I made an array of user details and sent to the desired page , but I am stuck in updating the score value once user logs in (like increasing a point for daily checkin ) and update in database . And also update user score as per performance in quiz. I am stuck in setting proper routes for the pages and simultaneously updating the mongodb document.

Comment: i would suggest that you use websockets or AJAX